# What is the meaning of "to make a fit"?

Tags: meaning

> 'If he had gone straight to France after the Kentish knight was
>   killed, men would have said he feared being slain like the knight. It
>   was his duty to show himself debonair to his English people as it was
>   De Aquila's duty to see that he took no harm while he did it, But it
>   was a great burden! De Aquila, Hugh, and I ceased work on the ships,
>   and scoured all the Honour of the Eagle--all De Aquila's lands--**to
>   make a fit**, and, above all, a safe sport for our King. Look!'

This is from "The Tree of Justice" in "Rewards and Fairies" by Kipling.

http://www.telelib.com/authors/K/KiplingRudyard/prose/RewardsFaries/treejustice.html

I do not understand the meaning of this.

to make a fit,

I am so glad if somebody kindly teach me.

Answer (score 3):

It's rather unusual syntax, so I'm afraid you're mis-parsing it.

The basic clause is "to make a fit and safe sport for our King" - *fit* is an adjective in coordination with *safe*, modifying *sport*.

The speaker has wanted to insert the parenthetical "above all"; and probably in consequence, has used the less common (and rather literary) form of the coordination: "a fit and a safe sport".